# qustion based on The fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration

Let f: [0,infinity)->[0,infinity) be a continuous function.

F(x)= 1+2∫(from 0 to x)f(t)dt.

1) prove that F>0 and F'>=0 (I proved it by the fundamental theorem).

2) suppose that f(x)<= xF(x) for any x>=0,
and prove that f(x)<=xe^(x^2) for x>=0.

I suspect that the second is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

From $$F(x)=1+2\int_0^xf(t)dt,$$ and the hypothesis $f(x)\le xF(x),$ you get that $$F'(x)=2f(x)\le 2xF(x).$$ Equivalently,

$$(\log F(x))'=\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}\le 2x.$$ Integrating on an interval $[0,T]$ with $T>0$ you get

$$\log F(t)=\log F(t)-\log F(0)\le 2\int_0^T xdx=T^2.$$

So, $F(T)\le e^{T^2}.$ Using again the hypothesis $f(x)\le xF(x)$ you arrive at

$$f(T)\le TF(T)\le Te^{T^2}.$$